# cannot get property of related table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am creating a website in Laravel. I currently have two tables: `users` and `cities`. 
In my models I have linked the both tables as following:

```
//User.php
public function city()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('City', 'id', 'city_id');
}

//City.php
public function users() 
{
    return $this->hasMany('User');
}
```

But when I try to get the name of the city the user lives in I get an error. I use the following code to list all users:

```
<?php $i=0 ?>
@foreach ($users as $user)
<tr>
    <td>{{{ ++$i }}}</td>
    <td>{{{ $user->firstname }}} {{{ $user->name }}}</td>
    <td>{{{ $user->city()->name }}}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

When I run it, this is the error I get on the line where I try to access `$user->city()->name`:

```
ErrorException

Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$name (View: /var/www/kljwaregem_2014/app/views/leden/simplelist.blade.php)
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong, I followed all the steps in the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships). Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To define the inverse of a OneToMany relationship, use `belongsTo` and not `hasOne`, as explained in [the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#one-to-many).

Comment: I still have the same problem With `belongsTo`. The error is now the following: 
`Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$name (View: /var/www/kljwaregem_2014/app/views/leden/simplelist.blade.php) `

Comment: @Jerodev use `$user->city` to access the city related to the user, not `$user->city()`.

Comment: If I use `$user->city->name`, I get another error.
`Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: I have found the problem, there was one row in the Users table wich had NULL for the city_id...

Thanks for the help!